Which webhook hosting service to use for whatsapp cloud api?
I have tried ngrok urls. But they are not getting validated.
Then I deployed my code on render.com with the GET and POST request having /webhook endpoint. When I try to configure it, the webhook does get verified ( as per RENDER logs) but still its shows unable to validate the url in meta console.
Servio.net is down.
